# Deploying a Go app in AWS ec2 got connection refused

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, devops

I have a compiled Go project that I want to deploy to an AWS EC2 instance. I just simply upload the application and run `./application` on the remote server.

In the terminal, the application is running and says he's listening to `localhost:3000`.

[image: Running app]

I've already added the `3000` port to the security group.

However, when I tried to access it in my browser using `<public-ip>:3000`, it always shows connection refused, whether I've run the application or not.

[image: refused connect]

I tried to run the app locally, it does work.

So is it because I deploy it incorrectly?

Comment: You state that the application is listening on localhost. The application must also listen on the public address.

Comment: Make sure too that the NACL of the VPC have an open rule in inbound and outbound for the port 3000.

Comment: Try: `netstat -tulpn` to see on what address is listening. If you see `127.0.0.1:3000`, it listens on your internal network, and you have to change to listen to `0.0.0.0:3000` (that what it means public address !!!). You also need your OS (probably is Amazon Linux) to not have its firewall blocking `0.0.0.0:3000` (by default the firewall doesn't block it - but that depends on the AMI used). (e.g. as advice, you can verify using `lynx` browser in CLI, or from another machine in the same VPC). After that, you play with Security Groups/NACL/VPC and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a bit difficult to help you because of no code being shared.

Some reasons why you got connection refused:

1. Your application is listening only localhost:3000
2. EC2 security group does not expose port 3000

How to fix:

1. Most applications are defining the host address on a config file or env variables. If you have access to change it, change it from localhost:3000 to 0.0.0.0:3000 to accepts connection from all IP or to your_ec2_public_ip:3000
2. If host address is hardcoded and you have access to code, change the code per above
3. If you don't have access to config or code to change the host address, then add a reverse proxy to route the incoming call to localhost:3000. This is a good link about using Nginx as reverse proxy https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/
4. Ensure EC2 Security Group allowing inbound connection for the designated port, in this case, is 3000 if you manage to route the incoming to your_ip:3000